# Set correct gnuplot version

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Due to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnuplot/+bug/1068815), I want to execute `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 gnuplot` instead of just `gnuplot` to create plots with `gnuplot`. I already put an alias in my *zsh* source file, so that when I run gnuplot from a terminal the correct version is loaded.

However, emacs's `org-mode` seems to be still using the old `gnuplot` version. How can I specify the correct version to be used? I already looked into `ob-gnuplot.el` trying to find the place where the command to execute `gnuplot` is saved, without luck.

Comment: Have you tried making a wrapper script and putting it somewhere in your `PATH`? (Be sure to check whether Emacs uses the same value for `PATH`).

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I'm not sure if I've done it correctly, but I just tried it. I created a script named `gnuplot` with a single line (`LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 gnuplot "$@"`) and put it in two directories listed in exec-path (in one listed after and one listed before /usr/bin as I don't know in which order the dirs in PATH are worked through). It doesn't work either. When running the source blocks the minibuffer says something with gnuplot 3.7, while in my system 5.0 is installed, so perhaps emacs has its own version somewhere

Comment: You can evaluate `(executable-find "gnuplot")` in Emacs to see which executable it'll pick up from `PATH`. If you want to check in a shell, there's the `which` command there.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Thanks! I found the problem: I should have specfied the full path in the script `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 /usr/bin/gnuplot "$@"`. In the original state it was entering a loop calling itself again and again. If you want to add the "Create a wrapper script" as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most robust solution would be to write a wrapper and putting it in your `PATH` so it overrides the binary you'd normally run.

You can check the result of `PATH` lookup with `which` in shells and with the `executable-find` function in Emacs.

In your case, the following script will do the job:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 /usr/bin/gnuplot "$@"
```